# Warning in React even after adding onChange handler: "You provided a value prop to a form field without an onChange handler."

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encountering a warning in my React application related to a form field of type `range`. Despite having an `onChange` handler, I'm still receiving the following warning in the console:

> Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable, use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [length, setLength] = useState<number>(8);
  const [numAllowed, setNumAllowed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [charAllowed, setCharAllowed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [pass, setPass] = useState<string>("");

  const passwordGenerator = useCallback(() => {
    let password = "";
    let str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    if (numAllowed) str += "1234567890";
    if (charAllowed) str += "!@#$%^&*()";

    for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length);
      password += str.charAt(rand);
    }

    console.log("re-render");
    setPass(password);
  }, [length, numAllowed, charAllowed, setPass]);

  useEffect(() => {
    passwordGenerator();
  }, [length, numAllowed, charAllowed]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
        <div className="bg-gray-800 p-5 rounded-md">
          <h1 className="text-white font-semibold text-2xl mb-4 text-center">
            Password Generator
          </h1>
          <div className="flex w-full items-center space-x-2 mb-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              value={pass}
            />
            <button type="button"> Copy </button>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center gap-2 text-white">
            <input
              type="range"
              id="length"
              min={6}
              max={16}
              className="cursor-pointer"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setLength(Number(e.target.value));
              }}
              value={length}
            />
            <label htmlFor="length">
              Length:{" "}
              <span className="text-sky-500">
                {String(length).padStart(2, "0")}
              </span>
            </label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="num"
              onChange={() => {
                setNumAllowed((prev) => !prev);
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor="num">Number</label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="char"
              onChange={() => {
                setCharAllowed((prev) => !prev);
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor="char">Character</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've already tried the following steps:

1. Ensured that an `onChange` handler is provided for the `input` range.
2. Checked the type of the `length` state to be explicitly `number`.
3. Reviewed the React documentation and related discussions on Stack Overflow.
4. Attempted to use `defaultValue` instead of `value`, but this led to other issues.

Despite these efforts, the warning related to providing a `value` prop without an `onChange` handler persists. I'm expecting assistance in understanding the root cause of this warning and finding a resolution.

Comment: The very first `input` in the component tree has a `value={pass}` passed to it but no `onChange` prop. Maybe the error is referring to that `input` in particular (since you're only talking about having edited the `range` `input`), maybe that one needs to have the `defaultValue` instead?

Comment: Oh got it. I was looking over `input range`. Actually the problem want `input value={pass}`. Thanks For your help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to address with respect to your question:

1. The error: You have `<input value={pass} />` without an `onChange` handler. That's the error. You have a controlled component without a way to control it. You should set the input to `readonly` if you want to make the input value change, but remove "user interaction" APIs.
2. The useState/useEffect/useCallback is not necessary.

You can replace the entirety of this logic with `useMemo`. You only seem to want to store a generated value when dependencies change. This is what `useMemo` was made for. Plus, this strategy will make your business logic easier to test.

```js
/**
 * Custom hook to generate a password for the user.
 * @example
 * const generatedPassword = useGeneratedPassword();
 */
const useGeneratedPassword = (
  length = 8,
  numAllowed = false,
  charAllowed = false,
) => useMemo(() => {
  // ...
  return password;
}, [length, numAllowed, charAllowed]);
```

Comment: Thank you solving my issue. I was looking over `input range`, but the actual problem was  on `input value`. Your efforts highly appreciated. Also thanks for giving suggestion for improving code logic

Comment: Glad I could help, @SanketKumbhare. If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as the accepted answer? This may help others more quickly resolve similar issues in the future.